# Order Wp query based on a custom field value

Tags: php, custom-fields, wordpress

I have written a wp query to list custompost types (motobikes) based on 2 keys. (brand which is variable and type)
The query works and lists my customposts properly, but I would like to order them based on a 3 key value which is the cylinder ('key => cylindree')
I did not find a way to order by a specific custom field value that is not in the query.
Here is my query so far :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'motos',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 
            'key' => 'categorie',
            'value' => 'Roadster'
        ),
        array( 
            'key' => 'marque',
            'value' => $meta_value 
        )
    )
);
```

[...]

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `meta_key` to order by:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'motos',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'meta_key' => 'cylindree',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 
            'key' => 'categorie',
            'value' => 'Roadster'
        ),
        array( 
            'key' => 'marque',
            'value' => $meta_value 
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly but I had to change 'meta_value' to 'meta_value_num',

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```
global $wpdb;

$query = "
    SELECT  
        wp_posts.ID, pm1.meta_value AS your_custom_field
    FROM 
        wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN
        wp_postmeta AS pm1 ON (wp_posts.ID = pm1.post_id AND pm1.meta_key = 'name_of_custom_field_in_database')
    WHERE 
        wp_posts.post_type = 'your_post_type' AND 
        wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY your_custom_field
";

$posts = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: Is there any reason why someone downvote this answer? I'm curious and I would want to learn if I'm wrong!